# Parse 2 images from JSON to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, image, uitableview

I am able to get single image into UITableViewCell. Here is the task i need to that is Get two two images into UITableViewCell. The code i've pasted below is i used to Parse one image. suggest me to do changes to Get 2 images.

```
 jsonDict = [jsonArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"imagess%@",jsonDict);
cell.textLabel.text = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageName"];
cell.textLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;

NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageData"]];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are getting in jsonDict: imageURL or imageData?

Comment: Default UITableviewCell has single imageview. If you want to use 2 imageview for a single cell, you will have to use Custom Tableview cell.

Comment: are you able to show image for one imageView? If yes then this is what you can get by default. You need to make custom cell if you require more imageview on cell.

Comment: ya its working awesome for one image.

Comment: Just add one more ImageView to your cell and loop your ImageArray for both the ImageViews or declare individually.

Comment: just return your array count at numberofrowsinsection delegate..show the tableview delegate methods

Comment: but i think it doesn't for get two images in a single cell @karthikeyan

Comment: store a json values in array and return it then make asyncronus call for image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i reached the goal, to show two parsed images in a single UITableViewCell
the code i've used is

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
if (cell==nil)
{
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    UIImageView *imageView1=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    imageView1.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,50,cell.frame.size.height);
    imageView1.tag=1000;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];

    UIImageView *imageView2=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    imageView2.frame=CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-50, 0, 50,cell.frame.size.height);
    imageView2.tag=2000;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];

}


jsonDict = [jsonArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"imagess%@",jsonDict);
cell.textLabel.text = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageName"];
cell.textLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;



if ([jsonDict objectForKey:@"RefImageData"] == [NSNull null]) {
    // photo is null
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageData"]];


    UIImageView *imageView=(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
}
else {
    // photo isn't null
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageData"]];

    NSData *refimage=[NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"RefImageData"]];


    UIImageView *imageView=(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

    UIImageView *imageView2=(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2000];
    imageView2.image=[UIImage imageWithData:refimage];


}
return cell;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass that has two image views in it. Then you can assign the two images from your json like you did here.

[Apple provides an example how you can do that](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html), also there are lots of tutorials out there, just search for "custom uitableviewcell subclass tutorial".